# How to delete a user from Realm database (in Realm Object Server)?

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

With iOS using Swift, I register a new user as follows:

```
let cred = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: username, password: password, register: true)
SyncUser.logIn(with: cred, server: RealmConstants.authorizationUrl) { (user, error) in
    onCompletion(user, error)
}
```

I can logout, register a new user, login a user. However, I could not find a documentation for deleting a user from realm database in Realm Object Server. Any ideas?